# AWS - How to share session between subdomain and domain for a Java web app?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, session, tomcat, session-cookies

I have a Java 8 web app running on a Tomcat 8 container that was deployed using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to an EC2 instance. I then configured Route 53 to point `myapp.com` to the Elastic Beanstalk endpoint as an alias, and did the same with `www.myapp.com`.

The problem is that when I login with either of them, the session is not shared with the other one. For example, if I login with `myapp.com`, and then try to access `www.myapp.com`, I'm being asked to login again. *This problem is reproducible vice-versa and with the logout function too.*

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18492576/3906773) explaining the issue and while I understand the theory, I'm unsure on how to actually implement this. I tried pointing `www.myapp.com` directly to `myapp.com` as an alias on Route 53. I also tried configuring EB to use an Elastic Load Balancer and checked the *Sticky Sessions* option.

Is this something that can be configured on AWS or do I need to configure my code to accommodate this? An example would be really helpful. The application is a standard Enterprise Java web app with JSP and uses Spring Security for authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need the Tomcat server to set `domain="myapp.com"` on every `Set-Cookie` header of every response.

There are many ways to do that. But the easiest way is to edit `/src/resources/application.properties` file in your application and set `server.session.cookie.domain` to `myapp.com`.